# How do I get hired for skills learned in classes rather than the outdated ones I've been using at my job?

Tags: job-search

I am a programmer with about 3.5 years of experience.  All of my work so far has been maintenance work at small companies using outdated technologies, and I want to break out of that.  I took this job while taking night classes at a university in a management program, which I've now finished.

Because I'm concerned about my knowledge being outdated, I'm taking online courses in newer technologies.

I don't have any problem searching for a new job on my country, but i want to apply to international offers to increase my number of possibilities.

How can I tune my CV or online resume to make myself more attractive to positions involving newer technologies such as the ones I've learned, when I don't have actual experience with them?

I am particularly interested in how to promote myself using https://stackoverflow.com/jobs but the question applies to any website that have job offers for remote work or relocation on a different country.

edit: changed boring for outdated on the title of the question to clarify

edit 2: Changed the phrasing of the question a bit to focus on the online application part

Comment: Your question is quite broad. You should focus it a bit. Otherwise it will probably be closed. Also, pure career direction questions are not on topic - this SE is mostly how to navigate your current position.

Comment: Thanks for the observation!, i'll try to rewrite the question, and well, i didn't find any other stack that would be appropiate to post this question.

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace.  I've made a fairly extensive edit to your question to focus it on your core question rather than on specific skills/technologies.  (It's received a couple close votes, which I think my edit addresses.)  You can [edit] further, and if I've misunderstood anything please do so!

Comment: @MonicaCellio It still seems like it's about resume writing or asking us what things to do that could be put on said resume.

Comment: @Dukeling we have other questions about how to represent things on resumes.  A question about what kind of experience or training to *get* would be off-topic, but this seems different.  If it still looks too "what to do" to you and you can think of a way to edit it, please do.

Comment: @MonicaCellio How to represent things on resumes I don't necessarily have a problem with - I think the problem here is that it potentially comes down to how the entire resume should be structured, and perhaps shifting how much focus is given to work experience versus classes. Not something that has a clear "this is what you should do" answer, but would rather mostly depend on the contents.

Comment: @Dukeling Hi, i think the edits made by MonicaCellio are on point about my core question, i want to know what things would make my online profile more desirable as a programmer, specially on stackoverflow.com, i hope that made sense

Comment: Do you belong to any organizations/groups where you can volunteer? I re-programmed the web site for my martial arts school, gratis, so I could use certain skills, have a demonstrated product to show, and could legitimately list it as experience. Also built, from scratch, a club management web application integrated with the web site for a different sports team/club I am a member of, using C#, because most of my work is maintenance in vb.net. Same deal.... keeps my skills fresh and gives me actual experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your resume is far less important than your portfolio. Put those new skills to work and create some projects on GitHub that showcase your abilities. These don't have to be large projects, just clean code that you can explain to others.
2. Since you mentioned that you're interested in work outside of your county of origin, and you are concerned about your language skills, work hard on improving your communication in whatever language your preferred companies operate. The number one reason I see otherwise qualified software engineers fail to move forward in the hiring process is poor communication skills.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, i'll wait if there is any other reply to the question, but yours seems on point about my issue, so i'll accept it as the most helpful in a few hours :)

Comment: I agree with this answer.  I've found little correlation between formal education and a candidate's skill, and have passed over candidates with a Master's degree or a list of classes or certifications for someone self taught based on either their work experience or side projects.  A GitHub portfolio with working projects showcasing what you've learned shows a lot of initiative. Many people go through classes doing the bare minimum and are not prepared to implement what they've learned.

Comment: don't bother with "continuing ed", if you're a developer, bother with "continuing development"